# Elasticsearch X-Opaque-Id Not in application.log Exception

Tags: elasticsearch

In https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/31521 Elasticsearch added [X-Opaque-Id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/tasks.html) to slow log and access log. One more use case for me is to link X-Opaque-Id to exception trace whenever ES throws exception, which would be logged in root level ES application.log

I'm wondering if there is any support plan or workaround to achieve it, that I would be able to link TaskId to ES exception trace in the log?

Comment: The elastic community is a better place for this question https://discuss.elastic.co/

Comment: Or potentially even a GitHub issue since this sounds like a valid feature request.

Comment: Thanks! created https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-x-opaque-id-not-in-application-log-exception/216739

Comment: Also created Issue in ES backlog https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/51451